# How to make text appear under the image, within a horizontal scrollview?

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-linearlayout, horizontalscrollview

I'm trying to make a `HorizontalScrollview`. Every image within the scroll view should have a caption underneath. I found some other posts saying to wrap the Image/Text views inside a vertical linear layout. But it doesn't work.

This is my XML:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text1"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:measureAllChildren="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/l1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/l2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
          app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

          <ImageView
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

          <TextView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:gravity="center"
             android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
             android:padding="2dp"
             android:textSize="20sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

And this is how I inflate the layout and adding images programmatically:

```
List<ImageView> mImageViews = ((MainActivity) context).getImages("data.csv");

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.part4, this);

    LinearLayout layout1 = this.findViewById(R.id.l1);

    for (ImageView img : mImageViews) {

        TextView tv = new TextView(getContext());
        tv.setText("Image 1");

        img.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        img.setPadding(0,0,32,0);

        layout1.addView((img));
        layout1.addView(tv);
    }
```

It produces a horizontally scrollable layout, but image and text are side by side. And text not below each image.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine for me . You can try adding a specific `layout_width` for the `ImageView` . Please try the below code, where I added a image from `drawable` folder and the text was below the image in the resulting layout. Try this and let me know whether this works for you and meet your requirements.

```
 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/l2"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

     <ImageView
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/about" />

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
 </LinearLayout>
```